# How to update the web3 API version in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, upgrading

I spent a couple of hours on upgrading web3 API to v0.15.3 in geth (on Mac OSX) with no effect. I installed the newest geth and it says:

```
web3.version
{
  api: "0.13.0",
  client: "Geth/v1.3.4/darwin/go1.6",
  ethereum: "63",
...
```

Which says that api is 0.13.0 (from Sep 2015) although geth is 1.3.4 (Feb 2016).

I tried to install the newest web3 0.15.3 with `npm install web3`
but it only creates a local directory `node_modules` with `web3` and some more subdirectories.

To be honest, I completely do not know, what to do with that directory and how to tell geth that I have a new version of web3. Geth still says `api: 0.13.0`.

Could anyone give me a hint? How to update the web3 API version in geth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like its cooked into geth here:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/jsre/ethereum_js.go#L2419

```
module.exports={
    "version": "0.13.0"
}
```

I'd ask [one of the contributors to this file](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commits/master/jsre/ethereum_js.go) to see if it needs to be updated yet. (I'm sure they'll update it as testing allows.)

[Here is a summary on each of the new web3.js major features.](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases)

Comment: Geth is hard coded, we need to update.. i will let the team know

Comment: This answer is three and a half years old. Is it still true that web3 in geth cannot be upgraded?

Comment: Now five years old. Any update?

Comment: it's been 7 years since this happened. the people have been waiting for the mighty eth developers, but no wind to carry our voice. will they ever update geth? would they ever update the documentation to reflect what is really needed? will the voice of people be heard? will never know.