# Geth 1.9.11 (and JSON-RPC) are still using a old version of web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Geth console by default is using web3  0.20.1, even in the very last geth version (1.9.11). Is it possible to use web3 1.0+?

```
{
  api: "0.20.1",
  ethereum: "0x41",
  network: "3",
  node: "Geth/v1.9.12-unstable-2a5ed1a1-20200225/linux-amd64/go1.13.8",
  whisper: undefined,
  getEthereum: function(callback),
  getNetwork: function(callback),
  getNode: function(callback),
  getWhisper: function(callback)
}
```

Comment: Related question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-update-the-web3-api-version-in-geth. From developer comments in geth's repo it seems that it is not possible to update to newer versions of web3 https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17330#issuecomment-411004731.